# Are there any SwiftUI functuins like html <details> tag?

Tags: swiftui

I want to toggle List like

```html
<details>
<summary>list</summary>
<ul>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>orange</li>
<ul>
</details>
```

I found [this](https://medium.com/devtechie/swiftui-lazyvstack-a-closer-look-ede4b653dc5d) , but it looks quite complex.

If there's much simpler way, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest equivalent is [`DisclosureGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup).

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  Text("Hidden until expanded")
} label: {
  Text("Expandable block")
}
```